# Retroactive update monthly

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, teradata

Let me explain what I want by explaining my tables.

**Month 1 -**

Table IMEI_SALES - This Table updates monthly. The sale_date column is the min(sale_date) of all the table. So there cannot be a another IMEI with the same sale_date.

```
imei              sale_date   month   tfm  tfm1 tmf2 tfm3 
------            ---------   -----   ---- ---- ---- ----
354205080163741   01/08/2017  201708  null null null null
354205080163742   01/08/2017  201708  null null null null     
354205080163743   13/08/2017  201708  null null null null
```

Current Month-

Traffic TABLE - Here I got the Traffic. Again there cannot be a imei with the same date. This tables creates and then drops monthly.

```
imei              traffic_date tr_month   
------            ---------   -----   
354205080163741   01/08/2017  201708  
354205080163742   01/08/2017  201708     
354205080163743   13/08/2017  201708
```

So at then end month. I have my IMEI_SALES TABLE and the traffic TABLE. What I need to do is to update the tfm's colums with the traffic. I can do this manually. So at then end of August Table IMEI_SALES should look like this.

```
  imei              sale_date   month    tfm       tfm1 tmf2 tfm3 
  ------            ---------   -----   ----       ---- ---- ----
  354205080163741   01/08/2017  201708  01/08/2017 null null null
  354205080163742   01/08/2017  201708  01/08/2017 null null null     
  354205080163743   13/08/2017  201708  13/08/2017 null null null
```

- tfm: is the traffic_date from the Traffic_date table.
- tfm1: is the traffic_date from the Traffic_date table next month
  (September).
- tfm2: tfm1: is the traffic_date from the Traffic_date table in next 2
  months (October)
- tfm3: tfm1: is the traffic_date from the Traffic_date table next 3
  months in (Nomvember)

The limit is current month+3. Let's see what happens next month.

**Next Month -**

Table IMEI_SALES. New rows here from  September.

```
imei              sale_date   month   tfm        tfm1 tmf2 tfm3 
------            ---------   -----   ----       ---- ---- ----
354205080163741   01/08/2017  201708  01/08/2017 null null null
354205080163742   01/08/2017  201708  01/08/2017 null null null     
354205080163743   13/08/2017  201708  13/08/2017 null null null
354205080163741   01/09/2017  201709  null       null null null
354205080132131   01/09/2017  201709  null       null null null
354205080163425   13/09/2017  201709  null       null null null
```

Traffic TABLE - Previous one is dropped.

IMEI 354205080163741,354205080163742, 354205080163743 match with the same date and within 3 months from the sale_date.

IMEI 354205080132131 matches with the different date and is within 3 months from the sale_date.

IMEI 354205080163425 no match in the traffic table.

```
imei              traffic_date tr_month   
------            ---------   -----   
354205080163741   01/09/2017  201709
354205080163742   01/09/2017  201709
354205080163743   01/09/2017  201709  
354205080132131   02/09/2017  201709     
354243774312421   14/09/2017  201709
```

When updating the IMEI_SALES Table, it should look like this.

```
imei              sale_date   month   tfm        tfm1       tmf2 tfm3 
------            ---------   -----   ----       ----       ---- ----
354205080163741   01/08/2017  201708  01/08/2017 01/09/2017 null null
354205080163742   01/08/2017  201708  01/08/2017 01/09/2017 null null     
354205080163743   13/08/2017  201708  13/08/2017 01/09/2017 null null
354205080163741   01/09/2017  201709  01/09/2017 null       null null
354205080132131   01/09/2017  201709  02/09/2017 null       null null
354205080163425   13/09/2017  201709  null       null       null null
```

So for example, Lets say I'am in December with same sales and traffic tables from september to December.  You will have to match

- Sales in August vs (AugustTraffic, September Traffic, October Traffic
  and November Traffic)
- Sales in September vs (September Traffic, October Traffic, November
  Traffic and December Traffic)
- Sales in October vs (October Traffic, November Traffic and December
  Traffic)
- Sales in November vs (November Traffic and December Traffic)
- Sales in December vs December Traffic.

I need to do this with Teradata sql and Powershell to automate it. Oracle is welcomed too. Is it possible with the limitations I just mentioned?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the particular problem that prevents implementing this update?
You struggle with the update sql? or with running it from powershell?

Comment: I know how to do it manually. I am struggling with the logic to automate it.

Comment: So your question is how to automate a query against a teradata database using powershell?

Answer (score 0):

How are you currently modifying tables? Any PL/SQL procedure? Can add on a trigger, which will make additional updates when modifications, or to update your current mechanism to update tfm, tfm1 field